# Pure CSS Hover Box Moving Page Text

Tags: css, popup, hover

Using strictly CSS, am trying to make a description box. So far, so good, it looks great. But one problem. When hovering over, it moves the rest of the page around to make space for the initial would be placement of the box. How can I get all of the text on the page to stay static when hovering over the trigger text?
Also, I'm using Drupal, Danland theme, not that I believe that would make any difference under the given circumstances.

```
    <style>
    span{
    background:#F8F8F8;
    border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: -200px;
    left:-30px;
    display:none;
    }
        span:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-right:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    left:31%;
    margin-left:-10px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    display:inline;
    }
        p{
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow:visible;
    }

        p:hover span{
    display:block;
    }</style>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>Angkor Wat<span><img width="300" src="http://www.lotusangkortravel.com/themes/danland/images/slideshows/angkor-wat.JPG"><br>
Angkor Wat central complex</span></p>
<br><br><br>
<b>This text should not move on hover.</b>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the position:relative of the spam. I changed the position to absolute and it works.

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your css

```
span {position:relative}
```

needs to be set to absolute

```
span {position: absolute}
```

then it won't affect the layout of the rest of the elements in the page. You'll have to modify the position to show the element where you want it.